# How does HTTP server detect and handle non-http messages using tcp raw socket

Tags: c, networking

For servers written in tcp raw socket like nginx, how do servers correctly detect and handle non HTTP messages among HTTP messages(skip those bytes and move to the next valid http messages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. If the first request on the connection doesn't start with a valid HTTP request line, it closes the connection. No other detection, no skipping, no moving to the next message.

A search for 'raw' at nginx.org returned no results.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's difficult for me to read source code of nginx decoding http, so I ask this question. It's important that TCP is stream-oritened. Every time when server socket detect non-http message, does server socket just close this connection?

Comment: Isn't that what I just said?

Comment: That's amazing.

Comment: The only thing that's amazing here is why you're asking me questions I've already answered.

Comment: I thought "the first request" means the server receive upon the client is connected. Maybe the non-http message appear after valid http messages. So I just want to confirm this situation.

Comment: The data in the input stream either conforms to HTTP, or not.  There are no 'HTTP messages'.  It's an octet stream that conforms, or not. @EJP has explained pretty clearly, IMHO.